# Css3 Media Query not working with max-width

Tags: css, media-queries

I have been trying to hide an element at a max-width of 980px using media queries but for some reason it is still displaying.

If I use a media query with min-width the element disappears but with this code it is still showing and I can figure out why?

```
@media (max-width: 980px) {
    .welcome-msg  {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with my code? I'm using FF responsive design view fro testing at the moment.

Comment: This is limiting the scope to screens with a width of 980px or less. Works for me.

Answer (score 5):

With your current `max-width`media query, `display:none` is going to apply until the document reaches a width of 980px, rather than *at* 980px.

From your question, it seems like you want the opposite to happen, which is why you've had success with `min-width`. Switching from `max-width` to `min-width` should solve things.

Otherwise, you are going to have to set your element to `display: none` in your non-media query css, and use `display:block` in your `max-width` media query.

**CSS**

```
/* Only applies while screen is 980px or less */
@media (max-width: 980px) {
.welcome-msg  {
        display:none;
    }
}

/* only applies while screen is 980px or greater */
@media (min-width: 980px) {
.welcome-msg  {
        display:none;
    }
}

/* if you must use max-width, this is a solution */
/* otherwise, use min-width IMHO */
.welcome-msg  {
        display:none;
}

@media (max-width:980px) {
  .welcome-msg  {
   display:block; /* element will only show up if width is less than or equal to 980px */
  }
}
```

If that's not what you are trying to accomplish, It would be helpful to have a [Codepen](http://codepen.io) example for us to better answer your question.

Good luck!

Comment: It is working for me here with min-width: [http://codepen.io/joe/full/znecI](http://codepen.io/joe/full/znecI). Just to be clear, you only want ``.welcome-msg`` to display on screens less than 980px, correct?

Comment: @lota Please try with max-width as I am trying to hide the element .welcome-msg upto screen width:980px; i.e when the screen reaches 980px; I would like to hide this element.

Comment: @lota if the screen is larger than 980px the element displays but if it is 980px or lower it is not visible!

Comment: I think i've achieved what you want by using two ``min width`` queries: http://codepen.io/joe/pen/znecI or using one ``max-width`` http://codepen.io/joe/pen/ymjvI is that not working for you?

Comment: @lota Thanks for your efforts I think there must be a bug in my CSS or summick as neither solutions work for max width. I'm going to keep investigating as I really do need to hide this element...

Comment: In your original question, you stated that you were testing "in FF responsive design view". Do you get different results with Chrome, Safari, or Opera?

Comment: @lota no I get the same result - NADA!

Comment: Okay, one more codepen just for kicks: [link](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/uzbDp) This is meets your criteria of:  "i.e when the screen reaches 980px; I would like to hide this element." Is the ``<p>`` hidden when your browser window is larger than 980px?

Comment: @lota haven't tried this yet but I thinking if the p element is what prevents the media query at max-width why would does it work at min-width?